# How do I run a certain dbt model that has a dependency on another model, thus making sure model A runs only after model B?

Tags: python, queue, dbt

I want to know if there is a way I can specify the order of run of each model in dbt or explicit state a dependent model which needs to run before the current model can be.

Answer (score 3):

One of the core features of dbt is constructing a DAG of transformations so that models are only run after their upstream dependencies have run.

In order for this to work, in your models, you should never select `from my_schema.my_table`, but instead use the `ref` macro to select `from {{ ref('my_model') }}` (or you should use the `source` macro if you are selecting from a table that isn't built by dbt). As an example, if you have a project with two models:

```sql
-- models/model_a.sql
select * from {{ source('my_source', 'my_source_table') }}

-- models/model_b.sql
select * from {{ ref('model_a') }}
```

At the command line, `dbt run` will always build `model_a` before `model_b` as it builds your entire project. If you just want to build `model_b` and any models upstream, you can use [selectors](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax#examples): `dbt run -s +model_b`. Alternatively, if you want to run anything downstream from a model, you can use `dbt run -s model_a+`

For more info, see the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/sql-models).